# Как убрать контуры соразмерные искомым дефектам на OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

Здравствуйте.
Требуется распознать качество намотки. Граница намотки представляет собой линию от края до края. Помимо неё отображаются отсветы на проволоке. Open/Close делать не могу, т.к. пропадают искомые дефекты намотки.
Подскажите, как можно убрать всё, что не является линией от края до края?

[image: отсветы]
[image: отсветы2]